# Does jmx create a new thread for each invocation?

Tags: java, jmx, volatile

I have a class with a non-volatile field, and a mBean in the get method.

```
class Foo {
   int x;
   int get() {  return x; }
}
```

Can I be sure that the mBean will get the latest value of the variable? 
More generally, how jmx invokes the methods, does it create a new thread on each invocation? (in this case, it is assured that we get the latest value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would get latest value depending on `x` being read/written in a  synchronized manner. If it is a primitive type, consider using `AtomicInteger` (or `AtomicDouble` etc.) to avoid writing synchronized constructs on your own.

Whether JMX creates a new thread for each invocation could be simply found out by adding following line in your `get()` method:

`System.out.println("get() executed by thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());`

This would print thread name and if it varies in each invocation, that means  differnet threads are used.